# creating and writing to a CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I am able to compile the code but I cannot locate my csv file so I do not think it is being generated.

The method should create and write to a csv file. What I do know is where is it being created and how to I define where I want it to be created if it is working.

```
def generateCSVfile(fileName,fileDescription,fileLocation,md5Hash):
    with open('deploymentTemplate.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        createRow = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        createRow.writerow([fileName,' ', fileDescription,' ', fileLocation,' ', md5Hash])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'deploymentTemplate.csv'` is a *relative path*, so the file will be created in whatever the *working directory* of your script is. When run from a terminal, the working directory of your script will be the same as that of the terminal.

Working directory can be changed using [os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) and obtained using [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) (after `import os`).

You may also provide an *absolute path*, e.g. `r'C:\deploymentTemplate.csv` on Windows or `'/home/drew/deploymentTemplate.csv'` on Linux to indicate the exact path to your file.

Please, read about relative paths, absolute paths and working directory on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 2):

To find the absolute path of your csv file (i.e., where in the file system it is saved), and to check that it was saved correctly:

```
import os
print("Output is located at " + os.path.abspath('deploymentTemplate.csv'))
print("File exists? " + str(os.path.exists('deploymentTemplate.csv')))
```

Possible output:

Output is located at C:\deploymentTemplate.csv
File exists? True